# Try and except to check and count returned JSON from API

Tags: json, python-3.x

I am learning how to get JSON data from a particular [API](http://collections.anmm.gov.au/api) using Python 3. I am using input() to select a word for inclusion in the url search string. I generally get the JSON results I expect which includes a count of records returned. However for some search words, the JSON is returned as expected but the except is invoked and the records are not counted. I think the problem is to do with the try and except. In my code the input words that work as expected include "pool" and "Pool" and the results include both "pool" and "Pool" but "captain" or "Captain" does not  give a final count even though there are records with "Captain", and the JSON is returned.

My code is below and a sample of the json also. I'd be grateful for any assistance with this:

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse
import json

what = input('What?: ')
what = what.strip()

url = 'http://collections.anmm.gov.au/advancedsearch/objects/'+'title:'+ what +'/'+'json'
#print ('Retrieving: ', url)

connection = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = connection.read().decode()

try:
    results = json.loads(data)
    #print (results)
    print ('Retrieving: ', url)

    count = 0

    if results['objects']:
        for item in results['objects']:
            objectNumber = item['invno']['value'];
            title = item['title']['value'];
            date = item['displayDate']['value'];

            count = count +1

            print(objectNumber,'',title,'',date)
        print(count, 'records with ',what,' returned')

except:
    print('No search results returned')
```

And my json sample:

```
{
   "objects":[
      {
        "displayDate":{
            "label":"Date",
            "value":1930,
            "order":3
         },
         "invno":{
            "label":"Object No",
            "value":"ANMS0427[063]",
            "order":9
         },
         "id":{
            "label":"Id",
            "value":88089,
            "order":0
         },
         "title":{
            "label":"Title",
            "value":"Article by Donald McLean titled 'Lure of buried treasure; from Carolina to Cocos' about pirates: Captain blackbeard, Captain Kidd and Captain Edward Davis",
            "order":2
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug your code, you'll see that there is a problem with this instruction's output :

date = item['displayDate']['value'];

Comment: Thank you I didn't see that issue. I have put another try and except around date in the for loop ( I am expecting the other data to be there). Is there a better way of handling this situation, like a case statement in sql? My amended code: `if results['objects']:
        for item in results['objects']:
            objectNumber = item['invno']['value'];
            title = item['title']['value'];
            try:
                date = item['displayDate']['value']
            except:
                date = ''
                continue`

Comment: if you're aware of all the values, you can create a dict to play as a switch case.
If not, I would personaly just add another if statement to handle any k:v for the date if they exist